# Custom Django model field for Numpy values like 'nan' and 'inf'

Tags: python, django, numpy

So, to store values like `numpy.inf` or `numpy.nan` in the database, I created a custom model field like this -

```
import numpy as np
from django.db import models

INF = 1.79e308  # large arbitrary number


def convert_np_to_float(obj):
    if obj == np.nan:
        return None
    elif obj == np.inf:
        return INF
    elif obj == -np.inf:
        return -INF
    else:
        return obj

def convert_float_to_np(f):
    if f is None:
        return np.nan
    elif f >= INF or np.isclose(f, INF):
        return np.inf
    elif f <= -INF or np.isclose(f, -INF):
        return -np.inf
    else:
        return f

class NumpyFloatField(models.FloatField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('null', True)
        super(NumpyFloatField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = convert_np_to_float(value)
        return super(NumpyFloatField, self).get_prep_value(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super(NumpyFloatField, self).to_python(value)
        value = convert_float_to_np(value)
        return value


class CalculationResult(models.Model):
    calc_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    result = NumpyFloatField()
```

Now the objects get saved fine -

```
In [6]: c = CalculationResult.objects.create(calc_id=25, result=np.inf)  

In [7]: c.result
Out[7]: inf
```

But when I get them later `c.result` does not return `numpy.inf` -

```
In [2]: c = CalculationResult.objects.get(calc_id=25)

In [3]: c.result
Out[3]: 1.79e+308
```

I would want the field to return `numpy.inf` instead of the value I chose to represent infinity in the database, kind of like how `DateTimeField` returns a `DateTime` object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the database you're using you might different results but none of them will be `numpy.inf`, because databases simply don't support `numpy`. When you `save()` a Django `Model` instance a record is created in database and all your object fields are converted into types that your database supports.

Comment: @Nhor I don't think you understood what I am trying to do. I know MySQL does not support storing `numpy.inf`. So, I am overriding `FloatField` to convert `numpy.inf` to `1.79e308` while storing in the database and convert `1.79e308` to `numpy.inf` when I fetch it from the database using a django query. e.g. like MySQL stores datetime in it's native datetime format, but when we get the value of a `DateTimeField` in django it returns a python `DateTime` object.

Comment: Have you tried overriding `from_db_value()`, like suggested in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects

Comment: @Nhor Thanks, that worked